# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5697: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pandas

Saw other threads for this and the common solution is to explicitly specify an encoder (UTF-8) when opening/writing the file. Another is to ignore errors. I've tried both but it stil didn't work.

Comment: We have no idea what's in the file and thus cannot tell what would be the correct solution. Please [edit] your question to provide more details; see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 0):

The file shoud contain something else than text encoded in UTF-8 or latin1 as `0x9d` alone is not valid UTF-8, nor latin1.

But it can be *many many* other encodings. For example it could be CP861, in which case it's a `Ø`. But I took CP861 randomly, it can be any other encoding that have a meaning for 0x9d.

It can also be an error in your file, or a file containing something else than text (in which it would have failed before position 5697 I bet).

If you don't mind giving us more information, it could help, maybe:

```
with open(source, "rb") as from_A:
    print(from_A.read()[5697-10, 5697+10])
```

Also, if you don't really need the content of the file, you can just skip decoding and re-encoding it by using the `b` flag of open:

```
with open(source, mode='rb') as from_A, open(destination, mode='wb') as to_A:
```

And if you're just trying to copy the file you can just use `shutil`:

```
shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```